# Useful properties for integration

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum, partitions-for-integration

**Proposition (1)**. If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R},g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ are  bounded functions and $P:=\{x_0,x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ is a partion of $[a,b]$ then
$$m_i(f)+m_i(g)\leq m_i(f+g),$$
where for every function $h$, $m_i(h):=\inf\{h(x): x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]\}$.

I want to prove proposition (1) but I have troubles in understanding it. I think the tesis of proposition (1) must be
$$m_i(f)+m_i(g)= m_i(f+g),$$
see: $A:=\{f(x):x\in[x_{i-1},x_i\},B:=\{g(x):x\in[x_{i-1},x_i\},C:=\{f(x)+g(x):x\in[x_{i-1},x_i\}$
\begin{align*}
&m_i(f)+m_i(g)=m_i(f+g)\\
&\iff \inf(A)+\inf(B)=\inf\{(f+g)(x): x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]\}\\
&\iff \inf(A)+\inf(B)=\inf\{f(x)+g(x): x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]\},
\end{align*}
And since $\{f(x)+g(x): x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]\}=A+B$ and $\inf(A)+\inf(B)=\inf(A+B)$, we have that $m_i(f)+m_i(g)=m_i(f+g)$.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: $\inf (f+g) \ge \inf f + \inf g$

Comment: Check $f$ and $g$ both with codomains ${-1, 0}$

Comment: Your mistake is that $\{f(x)+g(x) \,:\, x\in [x_{I-1},x_i]\} \neq A+B$. (In general.) Try it with $[x_{i-1},x_i]=[0,1]$, $f(x)=x$, and $g(x)=-x$.